# Convert NSString into NSMutableArray (specific String)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have String

> Test String is =====>{"Name":"0","Age":"0","Sex":"0","weight":"0"}

Want this String into Array of this type:

```
myArray[0]="Name";
myArray[1]="Age";
myArray[2]="Sex";
myArray[3]="weight";
```

Please help with the idea to crack this thing..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you dealing with JSON response/strings? If yes, make use of JSON parsers which will convert this JSON string to NSDictionary instance (key-value pairs). You can then access the allKeys array which will give you the expected output.

Comment: @Amar the problem with that approach is that, `allKeys` doesn't always return array in same order. Remember `NSDictionary` is an unordered collection of objects. But I agree with you though, that OP is not understanding this response as JSON, and he should ideally handle it that way

Comment: It's useless to get the keys into an array like that and not get the values as well.  Use a JSON parser.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra - Since it's clearly JSON, the source does not guarantee that the elements will be in any specific order -- the order of elements within a JSON "object" is undefined.

Comment: @HotLicks I know.. But OP clearly want to split the strings in a specific order. Which is not possible if you use JSON parser. Anyway the requirement seems to be wrong rather than the approach.

Comment: But if it's JSON (which is almost certainly the case), *there is no "specific order"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
    NSArray *arrComponents = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSMutableArray *arrmFilter = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int i = 0; i < [arrComponents count] ;i++)
    {
        NSString *str = [arrComponents objectAtIndex:i];
        str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""];
        str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
        str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{" withString:@""];
        str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}" withString:@""];
        str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"0" withString:@""];

        [arrmFilter addObject:str];
    }

    NSLog(@"Filtered array = %@", arrmFilter);
```

Comment: @Girish, that would be the reason of down-voting: `str = [str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@":\"{}0"]];`

Comment: @holex but whats wrong in it?

Comment: @Girish, it seems nothing is wrong, it is just ugly as the s*@t. :) I've got many down-vote because someone just does not like the ivar names because they hurt their eyes... there are many incompetent, envy or depressed people here, unfortunately.

Comment: @holex ok but I didn't think so.

Comment: @Girish, I'm not your down-voter. :)

Comment: @Girish : I think You are right.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
NSArray *yourNewArray = [testString componentsSeparatedByString:","];
```

I am not 100% sure about your test string, but this method returns an `NSArray` object based on your specific separator within your string. For more details see the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Comment: This is the exact way for creating an array from string separated by some specific character.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

// following code return array with 4 string objects but with character include {,},:,0

```
 NSArray *arr=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
 NSMutableArray *arrNew = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

//to remove those unusual character  from all array object

```
for(int i = 0;i <[arr count] ;i++)
   {
      NSString *str = [arrComponents objectAtIndex:i];
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""];
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{" withString:@""];
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}" withString:@""];
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"0" withString:@""];

    [arrNew addObject:str];
   }
```

Comment: Why would you do the `for loop`?

Comment: to remove unusual string from all array object

Comment: To be honest I was more looking at you up dating your answer. Answers that go "try this" and don't say why or explain there answers aren't very good answers. Please could you explain your answer.

Comment: Thanks +1 for the edit.